# Append before last tag?

Tags: jquery, append, traversal

Here's my HTML:

```
<section>
   <article></article>
   <article></article>
   <!-- INSERT HERE -->
   <footer></footer>
</section>
```

How would I insert content after the last `article` but before the `footer`?

I've tried doing this:

```
$('<article>Yipee</article>').appendTo('section article:last');
```

But that inserts the new `article` inside the last one instead of as a sibling.

I'm running jQuery 1.6.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

insertAfter is the function your are looking for I think:

```
$('<article>Yipee</article>').insertAfter('section article:last');
```